# How are iText PdfAnnotation Polyline vertices specified?

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to create a PdfAnnotation consisting of, for a simple example, an X pattern which I assume would be a SUBTYPE of POLYLINE (one or more discontiguous line segments?). If so then I think I'm providing the vertices incorrectly. If I specify vertices like this:

```
put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.POLYGON);
float[] coords = { 100f, 100f, 200f, 200f, 100f, 200f, 200f, 100f };
put(PdfName.VERTICES, new PdfArray(coords));
```

The following is generated:

```
2 0 obj
<</C[1 1 0]/Type/Annot/Contents(contents)/Title(title)/Subtype/Polygon/Rect[99 99 201 201]/Vertices[100 100 200 200 100 200 200 100]>>
```

and I get a yellow hourglass shape as expected, annotation title/contents are loaded correctly, and the annotation appears in the Acrobat Comments List.

But if I change POLYGON to POLYLINE (hoping to get an X instead of an hourglass), the (almost) identical PDF code is generated (Polyline replaces Polygon):

```
2 0 obj
<</C[1 1 0]/Type/Annot/Contents(contents)/Title(title)/Subtype/Polyline/Rect[99 99 201 201]/Vertices[100 100 200 200 100 200 200 100]>>
```

but a question mark appears instead of any line segments and no annotation appears in the Comments List.

I’ve tried variations such as trying to create a PdfArray of PdfArrays, placing all x-coords first, then all y-coords, etc. I have itext-pdfa-5.3.4 jars loaded.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Not sure that's the issue, but the version you are using (5.3.4) is almost [2 years old](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/534). Latest version is 5.5.2, you might want to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, I didn't realize that. I'll give that a shot now...

Comment: Didn't make a difference, but I'm glad you suggested that nonetheless - something that should have been done long ago. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind all. I haven't figured this out but, for the X and similar figures, I have the segment endpoints so I'll just use POLYGON to retrace through the line segment intersection points.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess but in [iText sourcecode](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/875c83115f93a27d0a703da0f0cb49dc2d841611/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfName.java#L1566) `PolyLine` is written with an uppercase `L`, that might just be it.